# How to play a custom sound from a UIImagePickerController camera overlay view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, uiimagepickercontroller, avaudioplayer

I have a situation where a timer ticks during video recording in a UIImagePickerController. When the timer crosses a defined threshold an alert sound needs to be played. I couldn't get this working in the production app and so created a small test app to make sure the issue was isolated.

I created a single view controller app which includes two buttons: one to play a sound (to make sure the sound is playing correctly) and one button to show the image picker controller. I set a custom overlay view on the image picker controller which contains nothing but a button whose UIControlTouchUpInside event is set to the same action as the play button on the initial view controller. Below is the relevant code from the only UIViewController in the app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Two Cheers" withExtension:@"wav"];
    self.soundURLRef = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundURL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(self.soundURLRef, &_soundID);
}

- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {
    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"OverlayView" bundle:nil];
    [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
    self.overlayView.frame = self.imagePickerController.view.bounds;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.soundID);
}
```

Before presenting the UIImagePickerController, the play action plays the button with no problem. However, after presenting the UIImagePickerController, the overlay play button does not play the sound.

I've also tried using AVAudioPlayer to no avail. If at all possible, I'd like to stick to AudioServices but at this point I'd like to just get the feature working.

(I've verified that the Play button in the UIImagePickerController's overlay is properly connected to the play: action in ViewController.)

[image]

[image]